# LVM physical volume priority

Tags: linux, lvm

Linux LVM can combine several physical volumes in one group and when spread space of this group among logical volumes.

If some slow devices will be added to group it may slow down all logical volumes. Is there a way to add device but allow system to use it only in starvation case?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what type of striping you want to use. You can control how logical volumes will span physical volumes by an order of LV creation and PV addition. E.g.:

1. add `pv0`
2. create `lv0`
3. add `pv1`
4. create `lv1`

So, now if `lv0` spans whole `pv0`, `lv1` will span `pv1` (in case of linear striping). Filesystem will use blocks first at the beginning of device, so in linear case, if FS spans multiple PV, last PV will only be used if filesystem is full enough.

If you need non-linear striping across fast devices, you may create VG only with these devices. Then create raid LV in it. Then use this LV as PV. I.e. create second level VG from LV. And then add slow device to this second level VG on linear basis.

Comment: Wow, really crazy workaround.

Comment: I had rather thought about built-in PV prioritizing.

Comment: Btrfs doesn't implement it yet too. https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Project_ideas#Device_IO_Priorities

Answer (score 1):

Commands `lvcreate` and `lvextend` have an optional parameter that lets you specify which pv to use (the pv must be a part of the vg).

For example:

> Creates a linear logical volume "vg00/lvol1" using physical extents
> /dev/sda:0-7 and /dev/sdb:0-7 for allocation of extents:
>
> `lvcreate -L 64M -n lvol1 vg00 /dev/sda:0-7 /dev/sdb:0-7`
>
> Extends the size of the logical volume "vg01/lvol10" by 54MiB on
> physical volume /dev/sdk3. This is only possible if /dev/sdk3 is a
> member of volume group vg01 and there are enough free physical extents
> in it:
>
> `lvextend -L +54 /dev/vg01/lvol10 /dev/sdk3`